# Making custom polymer elements not act statically

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to make a date picker with Polymer. On a page I want to place two of them, but they act statically. By that I mean when I click the button for next month on one, it changes in both.

I don't normally use elements like this so I never considered how multiple instances of a element would behave.

How does one make a element that behaves like an instance object rather then a static object?

```
<!-- I'm omitting the style and some script for brevity -->
<polymer-element name="date-picker" attributes="chosenDate">
<template>
<div class="picker" vertical layout>
    <div class="select" horizontal justified layout>
        <div>
            <core-icon icon="chevron-left" on-tap="{{lastMonth}}"></core-icon>
        </div>
        <div>{{monthName}} {{date}}</div>
        <div>
            <core-icon icon="chevron-right" on-tap="{{nextMonth}}"></core-icon>
        </div>
    </div>

    <template repeat="{{w in calendar}}">
                <div horizontal layout>
            <template repeat="{{d in w}}">
                    <div class="dateBox {{ date == d.day && d.inMonth ? 'today' : '' }} " flex>{{d.day}}</div>
            </template>
                </div>
    </template>

</div>


</template>
<script>
Polymer('date-picker', {
date : null,
month: null,
monthName: '',
calendar : [],
update: function() {
   /* code that figures out weeks/days */
},
/* these cause all instances of date-picker to change month */
lastMonth : function() {
    this.month -= 1;
    this.update();
},
nextMonth : function() {
    this.month += 1;
    this.update();
}
});
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

full codepen 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEJMpJ

Comment: If you put to instances of your element on a page like so `<date-picker></date-picker> <date-picker></date-picker>`, you get two instances that are totally independent of each other (`this` refers to the one or the other). If I add for example`this.monthName = this.month;` to your `update()` function, then this works fine for me. Maybe you could put some complete code in a CodePen (or wherever you like) that shows the wrong behavior.

Comment: Just did. My code for the actual date picking it terrible. But, my glitch should be obvious. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEJMpJ

Comment: Thanks. I completely overlooked the `calendar: []` assignment which is the culprit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What gets shared between the two elements is the `calendar` array. Since you defined the default value `[]` on the elements prototype, this single instance of an empty array is common to all element instances.

So for array and object properties, you should initialize them in the `created()` callback. Then the two element instances get their own empty `calendar` array.